# Google Site Hover Card

Tags: hover, google-sites

On a Google Site I want to be able to show a hover card with additional information (picture, etc) if the user moves his mouse over a name.

I've found ways to achieve this through Java Script and CSS, but I can't get either method to work for Google Sites.

How can I achieve this aim?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate you script ( javascript , css ) on the Google Sites with app engine. https://developers.google.com/appengine/?csw=1

You can download this Application , put your script in the cloub and communicate with your Google Sites. You need to install python for you Computer

http://obtiva.com/blog/50-deploying-a-javascript-application-to-google-appengine-in-30-minutes

If you need just to integrate only CSS on your Google sites 
you need to add Css code on the Html Box on your Google Sites.

Example :

```
<object>

<style type="text/css">

 .roll
{
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 10;
}

.roll a
{
padding: 10;
display: block;
color: #000000;
font-size: 18px;
width: 150px;
height: 18px;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover
{
background-color: #ccc;
color: #eee;
}

.roll
{
cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
<div class="roll"><br>
<a href="#">Rollover Texte 01</a><br>
<a href="#">Rollover Texte 02</a>
</div>
</object>
```